# Renovating the [regex] tag wiki

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tag-wiki

(EDIT: the wiki change proposed below was incorporated in 2015)

---

The [tag wiki for the `regex` tag](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/regex/info) has been growing organically for many years, and now contains a substantial amount of tutorial and reference material.

To the best of my understanding, this is not best current practice for tag wikis -- the page should explain the tag in the context of Stack Overflow, not teach people programming.  See also [What is a tag wiki? How do I write a good one?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214337/what-is-a-tag-wiki-how-do-i-write-a-good-one)

Towards fixing this problem, I have **drafted a new version,** but I hesitate to replace the existing one before receiving some feedback here.

The draft used to be at http://sopython.com/wiki/regex_tag_wiki_refactoring (EDIT: was removed 1/2016) and anybody with 100 rep can log in with their Stack Overflow credentials to make edits.

In summary, the draft replaces the current 17.5 KiB of Markdown with reference material and computing history with a somewhat more succinct 5 KiB (very approximate; excluding the proposed links section) version which focuses on common questions *on Stack Overflow.*

For what it's worth, my current definition of "common" is completely based on my personal subjective impression.  If you can contribute some actual science here, that might be useful.

(EDIT: draft was accepted 1/2016) My current plan is to float this here for a few days and see whether I get more downvotes or upvotes.  Ideally, some constructive criticism, or even (gasp!) actual edits to the draft would also be most welcome.  If the reaction seems to be towards the positive, I will go ahead and commit the changes.

Comment: Many thanks to the sopython folks for allowing me to use their wiki for this.

Comment: I think the regex tag-wiki is that way it is today, because of the questions which are folding in every day. And regex questions are just the prefect example for "Give me teh codez plz!" questions. [It's there where camp 2 and 3 meet up](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/252077/3933332).

Comment: @Rizier123 I don't see how that would reflect on the tag *wiki* -- would you care to elaborate?

Comment: I'll readily admit that I am myself responsible for some of the content of the tag wiki. It will probably continue to grow in *that* direction if we don't cultivate it a bit.

Comment: Removed the sopython wiki page now, as the change has been implemented and the tag wiki has received subsequent edits since then.

Comment: @tripleee: so update the above question saying that... I just went hunting for it. Also useful to note the date it was incorporated. I guess that makes this old question moot - also useful to note in an EDIT at the start.

Comment: @smci Thanks. The proper (though still slightly obscure) way to mark this as done would be to ask a mod to add a [tag:status-completed] tag but I guess they don't do that for content improvements.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One thing the new wiki lacks (and the old version buried) is the important "**How to ask regex-based questions**" portion. Instead it starts right in with differences between regex parsers, with phrases like "non-greedy quantifiers" and the like, which frankly I don't care about if I'm going to ask a [regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/regex) question.

I think the most useful thing you can do for someone who's actually reading a tag wiki before asking a question is get right to the point about what's needed for a good [regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/regex) question. We don't need a definition, we don't need to know the parts of a regular expression (just point them at [Reference - What does this regex mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean))

Maybe, after that, you can tell them when not to use a regex or whatever, and provide the links.

My two cents anyway.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.  I refactored the draft slightly to focus first on "how to ask" and then on common problems.  Does this address your concerns?

Comment: @tripleee Yes, I think the headings help organize the topics better. Thanks.

Comment: On the power of my two upvotes here, I went ahead and made the change.  I am accepting this answer to mark this as [tag:status-completed].